# SugarCRM REST API how to get the list of teams of the module

Tags: rest, sugarcrm

Is there any way to get the teams list which the current module record belongs to by using the REST API of SugarCRM Pro?

I already tried the `get_entry_list` by passing the relationship array with 'Teams' - this returns the empty array.

It should be the similar function to `get_user_team_id` but for specific module.

I also tried `get_relationships` method, but also no luck.

My guess because the Teams relationship is the Link clas, not the Link2 as all other modules.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the teams I believe you will need to do the following:

1) Retrieve your records using get_entry_list making sure to return the team_set_id field.
2) Once you have the team_set_ids, you can do another get_entry_list call to the module 'TeamSets' filtering those ids in the query parameter. You can then use the 'link_name_to_fields_array' parameter to return the individual teams on a team set.

An Example is below

```
<?php

$url = "http://sugar_url/service/v4_1/rest.php";
$username = "admin";
$password = "password";

//function to make cURL request
function call($method, $parameters, $url)
{
    ob_start();
    $curl_request = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($parameters);

    $post = array(
        "method" => $method,
        "input_type" => "JSON",
        "response_type" => "JSON",
        "rest_data" => $jsonEncodedData
    );

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result = curl_exec($curl_request);
    curl_close($curl_request);

    $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
    $response = json_decode($result[1]);
    ob_end_flush();

    return $response;
}

//login --------------------------------------------

$login_parameters = array(
    "user_auth"=>array(
        "user_name"=>$username,
        "password"=>md5($password),
        "version"=>"1"
    ),
    "application_name"=>"RestTest",
    "name_value_list"=>array(),
);

$login_result = call("login", $login_parameters, $url);

/*
echo "<pre>";
print_r($login_result);
echo "</pre>";
*/

//get session id
$session_id = $login_result->id;

//get list of records --------------------------------

$get_entry_list_parameters = array(

    //session id
    'session' => $session_id,

    //The name of the module from which to retrieve records
    'module_name' => 'TeamSets',

    //The SQL WHERE clause without the word "where".
    'query' => "",

    //The SQL ORDER BY clause without the phrase "order by".
    'order_by' => "",

    //The record offset from which to start.
    'offset' => '0',

    //Optional. A list of fields to include in the results.
    'select_fields' => array(
        'id',
    ),

    /*
    A list of link names and the fields to be returned for each link name.
    Example: 'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(array('name' => 'email_addresses', 'value' => array('id', 'email_address', 'opt_out', 'primary_address')))
    */
    'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'teams',
            'value' => array(
                'id',
                'name'
            ),
        ),
    ),


    //The maximum number of results to return.
    'max_results' => '100',

    //To exclude deleted records
    'deleted' => '0',

    //If only records marked as favorites should be returned.
    'Favorites' => false,
);

$get_entry_list_result = call('get_entry_list', $get_entry_list_parameters, $url);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($get_entry_list_result);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please edit your answer, and focus the code to the team_set_id and team_id retrieve logic (without details about how to make an API call).

Comment: You may be interested in this tutorial http://scriptbaker.com/get-list-of-records-from-sugarcrm-module-using-api/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Specify the team_name field in your request:

```
https://xxx.sugarondemand.com/rest/v10/Accounts/7e785902-ff39-4a54-87a4-e0d38b6b6ed1?&fields=name,team_name
```

Response:

```
{
   "id": "7e785902-ff39-4a54-87a4-e0d38b6b6ed1",
   "name": "15527-1",
   "date_modified": "2016-11-28T12:05:17-05:00",
   "team_name":    [
            {
         "id": "5272c830-5339-11e6-9195-06ef03a1f4b3",
         "name": "Team1",
         "name_2": "",
         "primary": true
      },
            {
         "id": "370d8fe4-e431-79fb-ec42-5565ecba3187",
         "name": "Web Service",
         "name_2": "CRM",
         "primary": false
      }
   ],
   "_acl": {"fields": {}},
   "_module": "Accounts"
}
```